# How to use java project in eclipse from clojure project

Tags: java, eclipse, clojure, leiningen, counterclockwise

I have an existing Java code base. It is organized into several projects in eclipse. These projects tend to require one another. For example:

```
 Project A -> Common Lib 1 -> 2nd level dependency 1
           |
           -> Common Lib 2
```

To utilize code from other projects I can go to "Build Path" "Projects" tab and click "Add"

Is there something similar that can be done for clojure code (in eclipse), so that I can easily start using code from my existing Java projects in clojure?

Comment: Are you wishing to call some code that is written in java from clojure or call code written in clojure from java? (or both?)

Comment: Call the existing Java code base from Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a fresh workspace.

Create a Java project java-project with simple class.

```
package com.pete23;

public class Counter {
    private int i = 0;
    public int next() {
        return i++;
    }
}
```

Create a counterclockwise Clojure project clojure-project with simple core.clj.

```
(ns clojure-project.core
  (:import com.pete23.Counter))

(def counter (Counter.))

(println "java " (.next counter))
(println "java " (.next counter))
```

Select clojure-project. Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects. Add java-project.

Start a fresh REPL (class path is not hot updating!). Et voila...

```
java 0
java 1
```

Comment: I really appreciate these step-by-step instructions, however when I start a fresh REPL,  I get `;; Clojure 1.5.1
#<Namespace clojure-project.core>
ClassNotFoundException com.pete23.Counter  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (:-1)` Is there something in particular you have to do for a fresh REPL? I tried closing the process and also restarting eclipse..